# Changing DateFormat to European in Widget, jQuery Datepicker (issue!)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, datepicker

I'd really appreciate your help on this one. I am trying to make the check in/check out date shown in the input field of the following page European format (dd/mm/yy): https://numberonebandbstaustell.co.uk/rooms/tremayne/ (username: 'numberone' ; pass: 'num270514').

At the moment it shows in European when you first load the page because I have simply set the value of the input field by php in that way. The problem is, once you use the jquery datepicker widget/device it shows the date as month first.

I got into the script file calendar-script.js which you can see by inspecting the element (script type="text/javascript" src="https://numberonebandbstaustell.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/nation-booking/includes/js/calendar-script.js") and changed the dateFormat option on line 358 to "dd-mm-yy" but it doesn't seem to do anything!

I've seen on other related questions on here advice to add the dateFormat by stating it when the selector is fired but being a bit of a javascript newbie I can't see where its fired. The whole thing applies to an input field with a certain class (hasDatepicker).

I'm happy for the backend of the website to read it in the mm/dd/yy format - it seems to need to in order to work out the rooms availability on the next page (i.e. when the text field is in european format as it is on first load and you select book now it thinks the format was american anyway so it breaks the system) but it needs to show the user the european format in the input field.

Hope someone can help I'd really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using datepicker, please add one option as `dateFormat` like below:

```
// I used class selector here as example
$(".navbar-datepicker").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'   // dateFormat, only need to add this line extra in ur code
});
```

UPDATE:

I checked your code by checking the source JS code. In this file `https://numberonebandbstaustell.co.uk/wp-content/themes/wpnation/js/allscript.js`, the following code is present:

## Check Out Date

```
$("#resend-step2 #check-out-date, .step1 #check-out-date, .room-content-description #check-out-date").datepicker({
    nextText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></span>',
    prevText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-left"></span>',
    minDate: dateToday,
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('resend-datepicker');
    }
});
```

Please change to :

```
$("#resend-step2 #check-out-date, .step1 #check-out-date, .room-content-description #check-out-date").datepicker({
    nextText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></span>',
    prevText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-left"></span>',
    minDate: dateToday,
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('resend-datepicker');
    },
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

## Check In Date

```
$("#resend-step2 #check-in-date, .step1 #check-in-date, .room-content-description #check-in-date").datepicker({
    nextText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></span>',
    prevText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-left"></span>',
    minDate: dateToday,
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('resend-datepicker');
    }
});
```

Please change to :

```
$("#resend-step2 #check-in-date, .step1 #check-in-date, .room-content-description #check-in-date").datepicker({
    nextText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></span>',
    prevText: '<span class="icon-chevron-sign-left"></span>',
    minDate: dateToday,
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').addClass('resend-datepicker');
    },
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment - I added the code you wrote above (see line 420) but no luck. I also added the one line (into line 381) which also had no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add your datepicker code, so that I can check and help, if I can

Comment: Sure :). It's here:

https://numberonebandbstaustell.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/nation-booking/includes/js/calendar-script.js
username: numberone
password: num270514

Comment: not the plugin code :) I need your code, means you must have written some code for `check-out-date` i.e. `$("#check-out-date").datepicker({ ... });`

Comment: Problem being that I didn't write it. I can;t work out how that one initialises. there are two calendars on the page (one when you click availability). For that one there is the following code:

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#nation-calendar-view-12').nationcalendar({ 
    calID:12,  
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {return [false, ''];}
   });
  })
 })(jQuery);

Comment: @mevukpaul, check my updated code now :) ... Hope this one will help you.

Comment: You utter genius(!) Thank you so much for your help. Is there anything i can do to pay you back in gratitude?

Comment: @mevukpaul, welcome and glad to know that it worked for you :)